# SQL Server - Contains Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains, sql-like

Using SQL Server 2014 and the following data:

```
ID          Address         City            State
1           55 Main St      Dallas          TX
2           4 Elm Blvd      Cupertino       CA
3           66 Walnut       Miami           FL
4           21 Main Ave     Cupertino       CA
```

I'm trying to use a contains query across multiple columns to find matches, but can't figure out the proper syntax. In this case, I have the query part:

```
CONTAINS ((Address, City, State), '"main" or "cupertino")
```

This returns rows #1, #2, & #4.

I can also try this:

```
CONTAINS ((Address, City, State), '"main" and "cupertino")
```

This doesn't return any rows.

What I'm trying to figure out though, is how I would return just row #4 using the search terms "main" and "cupertino" using a contains query.

So basically, I'm trying to do the following but with a contains query:

```
WHERE (Address LIKE '%main%' OR City LIKE '%main%' OR Zip LIKE '%main%') AND (Address LIKE '%cupertino%' OR City LIKE '%cupertino%' OR Zip LIKE '%cupertino%')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is for `CONTAINS()` is computed on each each column independently (as you might have guessed).  One solution is to try:

```
CONTAINS((Address, City, State), '"main"') AND
CONTAINS((Address, City, State), '"cupertino"')
```

The more conventional method is to add a computed column and use that for the indexing:

```
alter table t add acs as (Address + ' ' + City + ' ' + State) persisted;
```

Then build the index on that column.

Comment: Good call on the computed column, didn't even think of that.